# Can I completely disable Anonymous authentication for internal system with AD users?

Tags: php, authentication, iis

I have an internal system that has login form with username and password.

But recently I needed to get some more information about the user who tries to log in (in case of a failed login attempt for example).

Since it's an internal system, I thought to use the Windows Authentication to get the AD user which is trying to login. But, `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` was returning an empty string even though Windows Authentication was enabled. It only started showing the user only when I disabled Anonymous Authentication (So seems like enabling both doesn't get the Windows Credentials)

I still want users to enter credentials in the login form, but I also want to know the actual Windows (AD) user who is currently attempting to login.

Disabling Anonymous Authentication completely seem to work, and that I don't need it, but I'm a bit confused now, although I think I understood: Since all users already work from a Windows machine, their credentials are passed and that's why the Windows Authentication works. But now I wonder if completely disabling Anonymous Authentication may cause errors in certain cases and I should not disable it completely? Or maybe there is a way to enable both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication and still get the `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` value (and not blank string)?

But also, how does IIS verify the Windows user that is connecting to the website? Because if I just view the website with my user I don't enter any password or credentials

It's just weird for me that I use Windows Authentication, yet I keep the login form which seem to contradict the purpose of Windows Authentication. Or that's not correct and now I basically have 2 layers of authentications? I just don't know how the Windows Authentication works if I have nothing in the code that handles that - I mean how does it "know" that the user is allowed to view the website?

Comment: Check out NTLM and Kerberos. Dunno which one is used in practice though.

Comment: But it means someone in the IT team implemented these to work with IIS? I just don't understand how does Windows Authentication work by just enabling it. How does IIS get the AD user? Or it happens automatically?

Comment: Are you referring to IIS or LDAP ?

Comment: IIS, this happens even before I touch anything LDAP related in my code. IIS gets the authenticated Windows user of the AD